# Edit form: with grouped_select, how to show previously picked value as default in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using `grouped_select` for a reservation form, where room a room can be chosen based on the availability. Every time the user changes the values of the `arrival` and/or `departure`, the `rooms` (belonging to `room_types`) are adjusted according to the availability for this period.

When I try to edit the reservation everything works well if I don't adjust the arrival or departure date (e.g. the previously picked `room` and thereby its `room_type` are shown as default).

**Question**

When I change either the `arrrival` or `departure` date, the available rooms are re-entered in my for and the previously chosen `room` (and its `room_category`) are gone. Is there a way to show the previously chosen `room` as default if that room is available for the newly picked `arrival` and `departure` dates?

**Code**

reservation form

```
<div class="col col-sm-4">
        <%= f.input :arrival,
        as: :string,
        label:false,
        placeholder: "From",
        wrapper_html: { class: "inline_field_wrapper" },
        input_html:{ id: "start_date"} %>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-sm-4">
        <%= f.input :departure,
        as: :string,
        label:false,
        placeholder: "From",
        wrapper_html: { class: "inline_field_wrapper" },
        input_html:{ id: "end_date"} %>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-sm-4">
        <%= f.input :room_id, collection: @room_categories.order(:name), as: :grouped_select, group_method: :rooms, label:false %>
      </div>
```

JS

```
const checkIn = document.querySelector('#start_date');
const checkOut = document.querySelector('#end_date');


  const checkInAndOut = [checkIn, checkOut];

  checkInAndOut.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      if ((checkIn.value.length > 0) && (checkOut.value.length > 0)){
      checkAvailability();
    }
  })
});

    function checkAvailability(){

      Rails.ajax({
        url: "<%= rooms_availability_hotel_path(@hotel) %>" ,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: `arrival=${start_date.value}&departure=${end_date.value}`,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    };
```

controller check availability

```
  def rooms_availability
    hotel = Hotel.includes(:rooms).find(params[:id])
    arrival = Date.parse(room_params[:arrival])
    departure = Date.parse(room_params[:departure])
    time_span = arrival..departure
    @unavailable_rooms = Room.joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {hotel: hotel}).where("reservations.arrival <= ? AND ? >= reservations.departure", arrival, departure).distinct + (Room.joins(:reservations).where(reservations: {hotel: hotel}).where("reservations.arrival <= ? AND ? <= reservations.departure", arrival, departure).distinct)
    @hotel_cats = hotel.room_categories
    @hotel_accos = Room.where(room_category: @hotel_cats)
    @rooms = @hotel_accos - @unavailable_rooms
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

hotels/rooms_availability.js.erb

```
// debugger;
var selectList = document.getElementById('reservation_room_id')
function empty() {
  selectList.innerHTML = "";
}

empty();

<% unless @rooms.empty? %>
      <% @hotel_cats.each do |cat|%>
        selectList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<optgroup label=<%= cat.name %>>');
        <% cat.rooms.each do |room|%>
          <% if @rooms.include? room %>
            selectList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<option value="<%= room.id %>"><%= room.name %></option>');
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        selectList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<optgroup>');
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**Logs**

Start edit form (room 3, category 2)

```
Started GET "/hotels/1/reservations/6/edit" for ::1 at 2020-01-05 12:46:18 +0100
Processing by ReservationsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"hotel_id"=>"1", "id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Reservation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb:48
  Park Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "hotels".* FROM "hotels" WHERE "hotels"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb:49
  Rendering reservations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Park Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "hotels".* FROM "hotels" INNER JOIN "user_hotels" ON "hotels"."id" = "user_hotels"."hotel_id" WHERE "user_hotels"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/partials/_left_navbar.html.erb:20
  Rendered partials/_left_navbar.html.erb (3.3ms)
  Rendered partials/_top_navbar.html.erb (2.0ms)
  AccommodationCategory Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "room_categories".* FROM "room_categories" WHERE "room_categories"."hotel_id" = $1 ORDER BY "room_categories"."name" ASC  [["hotel_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/reservations/_test_form_edit.html.erb:24
  Accommodation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."room_category_id" = $1  [["room_category_id", 2]]
  ↳ app/views/reservations/_test_form_edit.html.erb:24
  Accommodation Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."room_category_id" = $1  [["room_category_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/reservations/_test_form_edit.html.erb:24
  Rendered reservations/_test_form_edit.html.erb (9.5ms)
  Rendered reservations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (21.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 330ms (Views: 322.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Change in date (room category changes to 1 and room changes to 1)

```
Started POST "/hotels/1/rooms_availability" for ::1 at 2020-01-05 12:46:21 +0100
Processing by ParksController#rooms_availability as JS
  Parameters: {"arrival"=>"2020-01-05", "departure"=>"2020-01-07", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Park Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "hotels".* FROM "hotels" WHERE "hotels"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb:150
  CACHE Park Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "hotels".* FROM "hotels" WHERE "hotels"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb:114
  AccommodationCategory Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "room_categories".* FROM "room_categories" WHERE "room_categories"."hotel_id" = $1  [["hotel_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb:114
  Accommodation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."room_category_id" IN ($1, $2)  [["room_category_id", 1], ["room_category_id", 2]]
  ↳ app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb:114
  Accommodation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."room_category_id" IN (SELECT "room_categories"."id" FROM "room_categories" WHERE "room_categories"."hotel_id" = $1)  [["hotel_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb:127
  Accommodation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" INNER JOIN "reservations" ON "reservations"."room_id" = "rooms"."id" WHERE "reservations"."hotel_id" = $1 AND (((reservations.arrival <= '2020-01-05' AND '2020-01-07' <= reservations.departure) OR (reservations.arrival >= '2020-01-05' AND '2020-01-07' >= reservations.departure)) OR (reservations.arrival >= '2020-01-05' AND '2020-01-07' <= reservations.departure))  [["hotel_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb:127
  Rendering hotels/rooms_availability.js.erb
  Rendered hotels/rooms_availability.js.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 20.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

Comment: From the shown code it is impossible to tell how the room grouped select would be reset. I presume the handling of the `checkAvailability` response is the culprit (or the rendered view of the `rooms_availability`). Can you show us that too?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will add the logs of the rendered view. Please correct me if you wanted to see something else, because I'm not 100% sure I understood your request ;)

Comment: Please show us `hotels/rooms_availability.js.erb`. I hope this will actually contain code that will reset the rooms. The problem I suspect is that the `rooms_availability` controller/view has no knowledge of the currently selected rooms, so it depends on your js code if it will or will not take those into account. Probably not :P If you show us that code, we can indicate how it can probably be fixed.

Comment: @nathanvda, there is no such file, the JS code posted sends information to the controller & consequently the available rooms are found/shown.

Comment: The logfile says `Rendered hotels/rooms_availability.js.erb` ???

Comment: So sorry, I overlooked it.... I added it in the question.

Comment: I hope now you also see what happens: it clears the select-list and builds it again (and thus looses the previous selection). Do you now know how to proceed or do you still need help (I presume the biggest was finding where it was cleared/reset)?

Comment: Thanks! Cannot believe i forgot about the file I created. I indeed see where the issue is created. Now just need to find a way to display the previously picked room + room_category (if those are available for the newly selected dates).